# Is not abstract and does not override abstract method doInTable(HTableInterface) in TableCallback in hbase

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, hbase

I recently changed my hbase version from 1.2.2.5.3.0-37 to 2.2.3.7.1.4.0-203. There is a code snippet(old code of hbase version 1.2)

```
public List<UserRole> updateUserRoles(final List<UserRole> userRole){
        return hbaseTemplate.execute(AUTH_TABLE_NAME, new TableCallback<List<UserRole>>() {
               public List<UserRole> doInTable(HTableInterface table) throws Throwable {
                      List<Put> inputBatch = createInputBatch(userRoles);
                      table.put(inputBatch);
                      return userRoles;
                    }
                   });
                   }
```

since now HTableInterface is deprecated . so i have used Table in the new code which is like this

```
public List<UserRole> updateUserRoles(final List<UserRole> userRole){
        return hbaseTemplate.execute(AUTH_TABLE_NAME, new TableCallback<List<UserRole>>() {
               public List<UserRole> doInTable(Table table) throws Throwable {
                      List<Put> inputBatch = createInputBatch(userRoles);
                      table.put(inputBatch);
                      return userRoles;
                    }
                   });
                   }
```

but now i'm getting error like "Is not abstract and does not override abstract method doInTable(HTableInterface) in TableCallback in hbase( which belongs to these two lines :

```
hbaseTemplate.execute(AUTH_TABLE_NAME, new TableCallback<List<UserRole>>() {
               public List<UserRole> doInTable(Table table) throws Throwable".)
```

Any help is appreciated .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You try to override/implement the method `doInTable` in the class `TableCallback`. But this does not exist (anymore) in the updated API.

Comment: So what can i use in place of that ?

Comment: actually, it more seems that that new method is added to the interface, and he is not implementing it.

Comment: can you help me get to know which method i need to implement.i'm new to this :)

Answer (score -1):

It appears you are using something that you shouldn't use (anymore).

> Is not abstract and does not override abstract method
> doInTable(HTableInterface) in TableCallback in hbase

This means that in the interface you implement, there is a

```
public List<UserRole> doInTable(HTableInterface hTableInterface);
```

method.

What you have done, is in the implementation changed the type of that variable from HTableInterface to Table, which doesn't match, and that causes your issue.

The interface you are implementing still uses that other class, it might be you didn't update all of your libraries well, or it isn't able to work with that new version.

So, check if there is another/newer version for that interface, and implement that instead, or you might consider a rollback to that older version.